# pfSense Internal Traffic Policy Based Routing

Tags: firewall, routing, freebsd, pfsense, pf

What is the current and correct way to apply policy based routing to pfSense internal traffic (originating from the firewall itself)? Creating a floating rule with the WAN interfaces selected, direction OUT and a gateway defined does not work anymore.

I enabled logging on this rule and it shows that traffic always originates from WAN1's address even though the gateway on the rule is set to WAN2. WAN1 is the default gateway of pfSense.

Comment: What is the source of the traffic you are trying to affect?

Comment: The firewall's own traffic such as if I SSH into pfSense and browse the Internet.

Comment: Browse the Internet from your firewall? *shudders*